# Intel quad core pentium vs i5

Tags: laptop, processor

I do not game or code...so is buying a i3 o i5 really worth the $200 instead of getting a quad core pentium say n5000?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HW Recs! Our site is best designed to give you purchase recommendations for hardware rather than technical details. If you would like a laptop/PC or CPU recommendation this is considered on topic for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel Pentium n5000 is an SoC (System on Chip) and is an Atom-based processor. You can't compare it with a desktop based or laptop series i5. The right question would be to compare systems as in whole. Specify what notebooks you are comparing and the usage you are looking to do with it.

A notebook with n5000 will feature low-load applications. It consists of burst speed i.e normally it would idle at a clock speed of 1.1 GHz and when required would top to 2.7 GHz. So, if your usage is limited to docs and limited multitasking than a notebook of this power is likely to be sufficient.

**Suggestion**

Comparing with your suggested laptops this is what I can suggest.

Instead of the two laptops, I'll ask you to look into this one. Matches all your need and has a better display than the Lenovo IdeaPad 330. [Acer Aspire E 15 - Core i3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HX333WZ). The core i5 comes with a beefy processor and a graphics card which from the likes of it is not your need. Hence, my suggestion would be to go for the newer 'Acer Aspire E 15 - core i3' which is more powerful and a bit future-proof and doesn't make a hole in your pocket.

Comment: Lenovo IdeaPad 330-15 Notebook, 15.6" HD Display, Intel Quad-Core Pentium N5000 Upto 2.7GHz, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, DVD-RW, HDMI, Card Reader, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, Windows 10 Home is $369 and Acer Aspire E 15 Laptop, 15.6" Full HD, 8th Gen Intel Core i5-8250U, GeForce MX150, 8GB RAM Memory, 256GB SSD, E5-576G-5762 is $599... best deals I have seen online searching Amazon, new egg, ebay and walmart, etc.

Comment: I will mostly be surfing, facebook, docs, school grades, occasional netflix, uploading pictures and videos to shutterfly, etc.  fear is that if I buy the  quad ....will there be things released for the faster processors in the near future that make the quad obsolete...and if I buy the i5  wasting $200 for a speed difference I will never really use.  I really need a card reader and I sometimes use my laptop at church to plug into screens for song words.  I want a couple of usb ports and optical drive would be nice on vacation.

Comment: I have updated my answer looking at your suggested laptops. Have a look.